# Type mismatch error when calling a procedure that returns a string array

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function procedure called `GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID`.

This is the code for it:

```
Public Function GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(lngGroupID As Long) As String()

    ' this procedure returns an array containing email addresses
    ' from the field [Office-Email] in the query qryPL_Email_from_Full_PGAL
    ' with the GroupID = lngGroupID as specified in the function argument
    
    'note that for some GroupID's, there may be only 1 email address
    
    Dim cnn             As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs              As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim strSQL          As String
    
    Dim astrEmails()    As String
    Stop
    
    On Error GoTo Error_Section
    
    strSQL = "SELECT [Office-Email] " _
                & "FROM [qryPL_Email_from_Full_PGAL] " _
                & "WHERE [GroupID] = " & lngGroupID
    
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    With rs
    
        .ActiveConnection = cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        
        .Open strSQL, , , , adCmdText
        
        astrEmails = Split(![Office-Email], "; ", vbDatabaseCompare)
    
    End With

Exit_Section:

    GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID = astrEmails
    
    If rs.State <> adStateClosed Then
    
        rs.Close
        
    End If
    
    If cnn.State <> adStateClosed Then
    
        cnn.Close
        
    End If
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    
    Exit Function
    
Error_Section:

    MsgBox "Error: # " & Err.Number & " Description: " & Err.Description
    
    If rs.State <> adStateClosed Then
    
        rs.Close
        
    End If
    
    If cnn.State <> adStateClosed Then
    
        cnn.Close
        
    End If
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    
    GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID = astrEmails
    
End Function
```

When I call the procedure from the Immediate window, for example:

```
? GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1)
```

An error message pops up saying:

> Compile Error:
> Type mismatch

This is even before it gets to the first line of code within the procedure.

I don't really understand this. The function is expecting a long integer, and I am supplying a "1", so I can't see how there could be a type mismatch.

If anybody could throw some light on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Its a little strange. I don't recall this from all my years of MSAccess vba (but I wouldn't have called functions in the immediate window that often). This works with a little wrapper: `Public Function foo() Call GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1) End Function` then you can use `? call foo(1)`

Comment: Your function returns an array of strings. What do you expect `? GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1)` to output? I don't think the error has anything to do with your function - I think it's related to the invalid use in the immediate window. You're trying to print an array, which is not supported.

Comment: Try `? Join(GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1), vbLf)` or `Debug.Print Join(GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1), vbLf)`.

Comment: Don't need wrapper function: `Call GetOfficeEmailAddressesForGroupID(1)` in immediate window will run without error - note lack of question mark. Question mark expects something to return. As @VBasic2008 suggests, Join() function will output 1-D array contents to immediate window as a string.

Comment: Hi folks

Thankyou so much for your help.

I should have realised that if I am calling a FP from the immediate window, there is no need to preface the call with a ?

so, thankyou all for your help.